# How to pass HTML input text value as a parameter to python function?

Tags: javascript, python, html, pyscript

So I have a python code, that I have implemented in HTML using pyscript. My python code has a function which takes in a word as a parameter and does something with it. How can I make it so whatever I put in the text field in HTML, gets passed as a parameter and calls the python function?

The alternative, if anyone knows how to do, how can I get a value of HTML element with python?

If anyone has any methods including javascript that can make this work, I'd appreciate that too. I'm just looking for any way possible to call my python function with the content or value of element.

I have tried multiple methods (ALTHOUGH I'm not sure if I did them right) and here they are:

I tried using cgi like this,

In HTML:

```
<form action = "/submit" method = "post">
      <input name="word" type="text" value="TESTING">
</form>
```

In Python:

```
import cgi, cgitb
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
text = form.getvalue('word')
print(text)
```

and text returns none, so no value taken.

I tried the form and @app.route method, but everytime I submit the form, it opens a new page and finds nothing, saying file not found.

In HTML:

```
<form action = "/submit" method = "post">
      <input name="word" type="text" value="TESTING">
      <input type="submit" class = "file_submit">
</form>
```

In Python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for,request, make_response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
  return "hi"
@app.route("/index")

@app.route("/submit", methods = ['POST', "GET"])
def submit():
   message = None
   if request.method == 'POST':
    output = request.form.to_dict()
    word = output["submit"]
    anagram(word) #this is the function I want to call, I want word to be what I type in HTML input
    return render_template("Pyth/py.html")
```

I'm new to web developmenet, but I have looked everywhere on the internet and I cannot find the asnwer to this.

Comment: Your first example also needs a wrapping `<form>`.  Did you have that?  An `<input>` tag is useless outside a `<form>`.

Comment: In your second example, the word is going to be in `output['word']`.  There is no `output['submit']`.  And when you call `anagram`, you need to store what it returns somewhere, and you need to send that back to the user through the `render_template`.

Comment: yes I do have <form> wrapped around first one, my apologies. I will edit that now. Could you please elaborate on how to send back to the use through render_template? and my anagram function I only need to call it, as there are other functions responsible for printing and returning values

Comment: You are wrong.  Printing and returning things in a Flask app are pointless.  The only thing the web browser sees is what you `return` from the function.  In this case, it's going to get `py.html`, but if you aren't passing in any values to substitute, then it's going to see static text.  That's NOT true with a CGI app, where whatever you print goes right back to the browser.

Comment: Do not use a form. Use an `input` DOM element plus a `button`. On button click read the value from the `input` element in either Python or JavaScript. For example: `document.getElementById('input_element_id').value`

Comment: @JohnHanley -- That's only good advice if he is going to handle the button click in Javascript.  If he wants a server round-trip, then a `<form>` is the right way.

Comment: @TimRoberts - With PyScript you almost **never** want a server round trip. That causes PyScript and Pyodide to be reloaded which is an expensive operation. For server notifications use the `fetch/pyfetch` API and POST data not forms.

Comment: Since he is using Flask, I assume that his use of the "pyscript" tag was in error.

Comment: @JohnHanley javascript works with that method but how do I make the button read value from input and pass it to python?

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm honestly new to all of this, there only reason I'm using flask is because I'm looking for a solution but if i can pass the value from input to python using pyscript, that'd be most convenient.

Comment: You need to know where you are heading.  Traditionally, Javascript runs in the user's browser, and sends requests to the server, where Python or PHP (or others) generates a response that goes back to the browser.  Pyscript runs in the browser, basically in a Python interpreter written in Javascript.  There are no trips back to the server.  If you expect to be writing with the traditional web server model, then you won't be using PyScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that does a very basic anagram service.  Put this in a file called `something.py`, then bring up `http://yourwebsite/something.py` in your browser.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import cgi
import random
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
if 'submit' not in form:
    print('''Content-Type: text/html

<form method="post">
<input name="word" type="text" value="TESTING">
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
''')
else:
    word = form.getvalue('word')
    anagram = list(word)
    random.shuffle(anagram)
    anagram = ''.join(anagram)
    print(f'''Content-Type: text/html

Your word is {anagram}.
''')
~
```

Comment: I already have an anagram function, my problem is passing in "word". that returns none for me.

Comment: I know that.  That's why I gave you the whole thing.  This DOES work.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but submitting it simply gives me HTML error 405 and opening something.py in my browser only prints the contents of the file.

And would you know why I keep getting none as my word? nothing gets assigned to it

Comment: Do you mean, in your Flask code?  I told you, you are fetching `output['submit']` instead of `output['word']`.  You need to fetch the text tag.